# Chef Supermarket IIS Cookbook

Tags: iis, chef-infra

I have a Windows 2016 Vagrant box which I have configured for local Chef development and testing. I downloaded the IIS cookbook, extracted the contents and attempted to run default.rb under recipe like this -

`chef-client -z iis-master/recipe/default.rb` (below is the output that I get)

```
Starting Chef Client, version 14.7.17
[2018-12-05T07:47:48+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 14.7.17 ***
[2018-12-05T07:47:48+00:00] INFO: Platform: x64-mingw32
[2018-12-05T07:47:48+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 3840
[2018-12-05T07:47:48+00:00] INFO: The plugin path C:\chef\ohai\plugins does not exist. Skipping...
[2018-12-05T07:48:02+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to [#<Chef::RunList::RunListItem:0x00000000062cc670 @version=nil,
 @type=:recipe, @name="iis::default">] from CLI options
[2018-12-05T07:48:02+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[iis::default]]
[2018-12-05T07:48:02+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [iis::default]
[2018-12-05T07:48:02+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vagrant
[2018-12-05T07:48:02+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2018-12-05T07:48:02+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["iis::default"]

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: windows

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* iis::default

System Info:
------------
chef_version=14.7.17
platform=windows
platform_version=10.0.14393
ruby=ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]
program_name=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client
executable=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2018-12-05T07:48:05+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2018-12-05T07:48:05+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 17 seconds
[2018-12-05T07:48:05+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/users/vagrant/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.ou
t
[2018-12-05T07:48:05+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2018-12-05T07:48:05+00:00] FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: 412 "Precondition Failed"
```

My question is- which Windows cookbook is it talking about? I downloaded the entire IIS cookbook directory and didn't edit a thing in it but I can't seem to figure out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iis cookbook [has a dependency on windows cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/iis/blob/master/metadata.rb#L9).
you should download not only the iis cookbook, but all of its dependencies in recursive manner. gladly, you can leverage [berkshelf](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf) for this.